# python 3x program not correctly returning/displaying variable values

Tags: python-3.x

Question has been fixed up, sorry if I have forgotten any other important information.

I am struggling with why my program can't calculate the tuition fee.
here is my code.
it is meant to ask the user to input a code type (pyhton, C++ or java) which works fine
it then asks the user to input the number of lessons/additional hours and tests that they would like to sit which is also working fine from what i can tell.
i believe the feecalc function is causing the problem but i get no actual errors when running it besides the fact that when the feecalc function goes to print the results, it prints the string but the variable has no value? or its value has been changed but im not sure as to why this is happening.

i apologise for pasting lots of code but im unsure as to what is causing this problem exactly as it runs 'fine'. is this a logical error or have I made a simple mistake that i am overlooking?

```
test data   
code = python  
number of lessons = 2  
additional hours = 3  
tests = 1
```

output is as follows

```
 Welcome to Dr Ho Coaching Centre fee calculator
what code do you wish to study?
Python - Java - C++
>python
thank you for choosing python
How many lessons would you like?2
How many additional hours would you like?3
how many tests would you like to sit?1

python
Tuition fee for the lessons is $ 
Tuition fee for the additional hours is $ 
Tuition fee for the total tests is $ 
Total Tuition fee is $ 
Would you like to calculate the Tuition fee for another student?
```

as seen there is no calculated price displaying. and i have removed a few printed strings from the test data as i could not format it correctly within this forum, sorry if that changes anything.
.

```
def body( ):
    codeofstudy = ''
    tlessons = ''
    xhours = ''
    tests = ''
    totalcost = ''
    lessoncost = ''
    xhourscost = ''
    testscost = ''
    print('''
-------------------------------------------------
Welcome to Dr Ho Coaching Centre fee calculator
-------------------------------------------------''')
codeofstudy = codecheck(codeofstudy)
studytime(tlessons, xhours, tests)
print(tlessons)
feecalc(codeofstudy, tlessons, xhours, tests, lessoncost, xhourscost, testscost, totalcost)
print('Tuition fee for the lessons is $',lessoncost)
print('Tuition fee for the additional hours is $', xhourscost)
print('Tuition fee for the total tests is $', testscost)
print('Total Tuition fee is $', totalcost)
rerun()



def codecheck(codeofstudy):
codeofstudy = input('''what code do you wish to study?
Python - Java - C++
>''')
if codeofstudy in {"python", "Python", "Java", "java", "C++", "c++"}:
    print('thank you for choosing', codeofstudy)
    return codeofstudy
else:
    print('That is not a valid answer')
    codecheck(codeofstudy)


def studytime(tlessons, xhours, tests):
tlessons = input('How many lessons would you like?')
xhours = input('How many additional hours would you like?')
tests = input('how many tests would you like to sit?')
tlessons = int(tlessons)
xhours = int(xhours)
tests = int(tests)
return tlessons, xhours, test


def feecalc(codeofstudy, tlessons, xhours, tests, lessoncost, xhourcost, testscost, totalcost):
if codeofstudy in ("python", "Python"):
    print('python')
    lessoncost = tlessons * 300
    xhourscost = xhours * 200
    testscost = tests * 250
    totalcost = lessoncost + xhourscost + testscost
    return lessoncost, xhourscost, testscost, totalcost

elif codeofstudy in ("java", "Java"):
    print('java')
    lessoncost = tlessons * 200
    xhourscost = xhours * 150
    testscost = tests * 150
    totalcost = lessoncost + xhourscost + testscost
    return lessoncost, xhourscost, testscost, totalcost

elif codeofstudy in ("c++", "C++"):
    print('C++')
    lessoncost = tlessons * 175
    xhourscost = xhours * 175
    testscost = tests * 170
    totalcost = lessoncost + xhourscost + testscost
    return lessoncost, xhourscost, testscost, totalcost

def rerun():
rerun = ' '
rerun = input('Would you like to calculate the Tuition fee for another student?')
if rerun in ("y", "Y"):
    body()
body()
```

Thanks in advance for any help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared all your variables with value empty string '', you print them with the default values. `studytime()` assigning values to 3 local variables(scope belongs to the method only), the variables tlessons, xhours and test that declared outside of `studytime()` hadn't assigned any new values.

You need to change your code as:

```
tlessons, xhours, test = studytime(tlessons, xhours, tests)
```

return the values and assign them to corresponding variables

For example

```
def test(x):
    x = 10
    return x



x = 0
test(x)
print(x)  # output is 0

x = test(x)
print(x)  # output is 10
```

Comment: Thank you haifzhan, turns out that was part of the problem but i applied what you said to other parts of the program and got it working :)
thanks a million (Y)